# Mongo not running after fresh MEAN installation

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I am new to the MEAN stack, so I was reading the official documentation: learn.mean.io and after following the very basic steps of installing Mongo, npm, gulp, etc, after I run the app with gulp, I get the following error:

Error: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Of course this has to do with mongo not running on that specific port, and I could download mongo separately and run it, but isn't MEAN supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't run the mongod server.. The application will only create the connection. using ip and port.. Mongo Db you have to setup seperately

Answer (score 0):

After installing Mongo DB and other tools to setup MEAN Stack, you need to start the Mongo DB Server using Command Prompt.

Assume that I have Mongo DB installed in a folder named "Projects" in Local Disk : D and I have two folders named Data and db in Disk D itself as follows

```
D://Projects/mongodb
D://Data/db

1. Open Command Prompt ( CMD )
2. Browse to the folder in which Mongo DB is installed.
3. Create a folder named "Data" and inside Data, another folder named "db". this should reside in the local disk where Mongo DB is installed.
4. To run mongodb server, open CMD in the mongodb installed folder and type "mongod --dbpath=" with your respective path.
5. as per my config: mongod --dbpath=d:/data/db ( i have my data & db folder outside of projects folder )
6. this should start the server with a message, "waiting for connections on port: 27017"
7. after starting the server, you may launch your app or mongo shell to connect to the mongodb server.
```

In the config file, your may add the path so that you need not specify it all the time when you fire up the server.